# dot product in python

Tags: python, dot-product

Does this Python code actually find the dot product of two vectors?

```
import operator

vector1 = (2,3,5)
vector2 = (3,4,6)
dotProduct = reduce( operator.add, map( operator.mul, vector1, vector2))
```

Comment: Seems like it will, yes, why are you asking?

Comment: This would have better been asked "How to do Dot Product in (Vanilla) Python", or something to that effect.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can also use the numpy implementation of [dot product](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html) which has large array optimizations in native code to make computations slightly faster. Even better unless you are specifically trying to write a dot product routine or avoid dependencies, using a tried tested widely used library is much better than rolling your own.

Answer (score 48):

Yes it does. Here is another way

```
>>> sum(map( operator.mul, vector1, vector2))
48
```

and another that doesn't use `operator` at all

```
>>> vector1 = (2,3,5)
>>> vector2 = (3,4,6)
>>> sum(p*q for p,q in zip(vector1, vector2))
48
```

Comment: nice, the only thing is that you missed the [] of the list comprehension.

Comment: @chuse, there is no list comprehension, it's a generator expression

Comment: wow, I didn't knew that this existed. In fact, I always used stuff like `sum(map(lambda x:f(x), list))`, then I went to `sum([ f(x) for x in list])`, now I can do `sum(f(x) for x in list)`. Cool.