# Geometric properties of connected components - Image Processing

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have a binary Image with many connected components. I want to determine geometric properties of these components (like if it represents straight line, or its a curve etc). how it can be done?

thanks in advance.

Comment: you can compute the curvature to differentiate straight lines and curves.

Comment: @chaohuang do matlab has some inbuilt function for that?

Comment: There is no built-in function for your purpose, but [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/32696) may help. Also, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11317579/surface-curvature-matlab-equivalent-in-python) and [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/152405)

Comment: @crack_addict: MATLAB has [`regionprops`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/regionprops.html): not for curvature, but it computes different measures that can be useful (eccentricity maybe)