# Edge detection for 3d point clouds/meshes with R

Tags: r, edge-detection, point-clouds

The detection of edges in 3d objects may be the first step for the automatic processing of particular characteristics and landmarks.

Thus, I'm looking for a method to identify such edges for some of my 3d-scanned objects.

However, with all my ideas (Hough transformation, angles threshold for neighboring vertices) I didn't succeed.

Thus, I'd be quite happy if someone could point me to a solution to the edge-finding-problem for 3d point clouds which can be applied using R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [nice paper from last year about this topic](https://www.google.es/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.ethz.ch/content/dam/ethz/special-interest/baug/igp/photogrammetry-remote-sensing-dam/documents/pdf/timo-jan-cvpr2016.pdf&ved=0ahUKEwjEx7Ogjr_SAhUBaxQKHVmhAUIQFggdMAA&usg=AFQjCNEaOI3MKERgrBIlh1C7k8VghCiFHQ&sig2=K23UcC1pToHmOfs_wnJrPg).

Basically, you need to compute several features, for each point, based on it's neighbors.

I usually prefer Python over R so I'm not aware of any point-cloud processing package un R. But the implementation of that paper in R should be easy.

If you can translate Python-R, you can [take a look at this library](https://github.com/daavoo/pyntcloud) that I wrote as it has already implemented the computation of all the features mentioned on that paper.

If that helps you, [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42476839/is-gaussian-mean-curvatures-applicable-for-rough-surfaces/42489903?noredirect=1#comment72136158_42489903) you can find example code on how to add the curvature for each point. You just have to replace the word curvature with the other names of features.